# Are Lévy processes absolutely continuous?

Tags: stochastic-processes, models

If $X_t$ is a Lévy process, is it absolutely continuous? Meaning, does it have a density?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is ''no''. Lévy processes do not necessarily have a density.

An accessible (and excellent) book on the topic was written by [Cont and Tankov (2004)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Financial-Modelling-Processes-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/1584884134). The introduction to chapter 11.1.3 reads as

> Contrary to the classical Black-Scholes case, in exponential Lévy models
>   there are no explicit formulae for call option prices, **because the probability
>   density of a Lévy process is typically not known in closed form**. However, the
>   characteristic function of this density can be expressed in terms of elementary functions for the majority of Lévy processes discussed in the literature. This has led to the development of Fourier-based option pricing methods for exponential Lévy models. In these methods, one needs to evaluate one Fourier transform numerically.

These Fourier methods were developed by Carr and Madan (1999) who discuss the fast Fourier transform, Lewis (2001) who consideres generalised Fourier transforms of option payoffs and Bakshi and Madan (2000) who provide deep economical intuition and come up with a Black-Scholes like formula.

In some cases, you may find closed-form option prices. Obviously, the geometric Brownian motion from Black and Scholes (1973) is an exponential Lévy process. So is the jump-diffusion from Kou (2002) and even for the variance gamma process, you have ''closed form'' solutions (using modified Bessel functions and other special functions). Note that the above models also have a closed form density function. But in general, you have to use Fourier methods. Look at the CGMY model from Carr et al. (2002) which generalises the variance gamma process and cannot be described by a single SDE. Such Lévy processes are typically characterised by a Lévy triplet (deterministic mean, variance (diffusion part) and jump component).

Note that Fourier methods are not restricted to exponential Lévy models. They also apply to most stochastic volatility models, most notably the Heston (1993) model. Some extensions of the basic Fourier methods however do require independent increments and exclude stochastic volatility models.